# Oracle SQL Developer: How Do I Initialize A Row Type Parameter

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I am very new to Oracle. I am trying to debug a proc that has a rowtype/table as a parameter. (P_INVENTORY_BIN_NUMBERS) How do I initialize the yellow highlighted section given [Debugger Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/waCf0.png)

and these are the declarations

```sql
create or replace PACKAGE PG_MV_INVENTORY_IUD AS

TYPE inventory_array IS TABLE of NUMBER(18) INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER

PROCEDURE ISSUE_INVENTORY (P_INVENTORY_BIN_NUMBERS IN inventory_array,
P_INVENTORY_CODE IN VARCHAR2,
P_COUNTY_CODE IN NUMBER,
P_AGENCY_CODE IN NUMBER,
P_PLATE_NUMBER IN VARCHAR2,
P_AGENT_CUSTOMER_NUMBER IN VARCHAR2,
P_DECAL_YEAR IN VARCHAR2,
P_USED_DATE IN DATE,
P_INVENTORY_CONFIG OUT VARCHAR2);
END PG_MV_INVENTORY_IUD;

create or replace PACKAGE BODY PG_MV_INVENTORY_IUD AS

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

PROCEDURE ISSUE_INVENTORY_BIN_NUM (P_INVENTORY_BIN_NUMBERS IN inventory_array,
P_INVENTORY_CODE IN VARCHAR2,
P_COUNTY_CODE IN NUMBER,
P_AGENCY_CODE IN NUMBER,
P_PLATE_NUMBER IN VARCHAR2,
P_DECAL_YEAR IN VARCHAR2,
P_USED_DATE IN DATE,
P_INVENTORY_CONFIG OUT VARCHAR2)
AS
Inv Inventory%rowtype;
BEGIN
```

I tried to use a cursor, but I got a wrong type error.

Comment: Your package signature is invalid as you are missing a `;` after `BINARY_INTEGER`.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have a `ROWTYPE` parameter; you have an associative array. Declare it as you would any other variable and then assign values to the indexes and pass it to the procedure:

```sql
DECLARE
  v_inventory_bin_numbers PG_MV_INVENTORY_IUD.inventory_array;
  v_inventory_config      VARCHAR2(20);
BEGIN
  v_inventory_bin_numbers(42) := 17;
  v_inventory_bin_numbers(63) := 3;
  v_inventory_bin_numbers(74) := 19;

  PG_MV_INVENTORY_IUD.ISSUE_INVENTORY (
    P_INVENTORY_BIN_NUMBERS => v_inventory_bin_numbers,
    P_INVENTORY_CODE        => NULL,
    P_COUNTY_CODE           => NULL,
    P_AGENCY_CODE           => NULL,
    P_PLATE_NUMBER          => NULL,
    P_AGENT_CUSTOMER_NUMBER => NULL,
    P_DECAL_YEAR            => NULL,
    P_USED_DATE             => NULL,
    P_INVENTORY_CONFIG      => v_inventory_config
  );
END;
/
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/UJZjruPf)